# get Usercredentials of logged in User from WebSphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-was

i am looking for some examples or just java classes, to get Usercredentials like Username and Password of currently logged in user in a websphere application server, *which use a ldap repository.(edited)*

is there anybody who has experience and know which classes of ibm do i need?

i want to determine which user is logged in and what password and unique id the user has, in java.

Comment: It varies depending on the context.  Are you trying to get this information in a servlet, JAX-RS resource, EJB, or something else?  In any case, you're unlikely to be able to access the password.

Comment: my program will work on websphere. and i think it is better to make a EJB, because of security service. but in the other hand a RESTful API, because it has just to execute when it gets an http request in form a GET or POST. so i am looking for the easiest way.